# Triggering click on a link doesn't change location hash

Tags: javascript, jquery, fragment-identifier

I'm working on a web application that uses `onHashChange` event listener in some situations and manually clicking on a link with `href="#hash"` works perfectly well.
But when I trigger click on the same link using jQuery's `$('a[href=#"hash"]').trigger('click')` or `$('a[href=#"hash"]').click()` hash in address bar is not changing.

Is it something that I'm doing wrong? or I shoud use another method for this purpose?

**HTML**

```
<a href="#hash">Do Something</a>
```

**JS**

```
// Not working
$('a[href="#hash"]').click();

// Not working
$('a[href="#hash"]').trigger('click');
```

Comment: Can you demonstrate this using a fiddle?

Comment: Do you `preventDefault()` in your click handler?

Comment: Silly Question. Why trigger a click on the link? Why not just handle it all programatically?

Comment: @allnodcoms Imagine a page that when loads with a url hash does something based on url's hash. and changing hash does the same thing. I want to create a default hash that if user opened the page without any hash in url, I simulate clicking on a default button. Sorry if my question doesn't describe the situation very well; but beleive me it's not as silly as you might think it is!

Comment: @FaridRn - I have used this method before, but rather than going through the link, just set 'window.location'... Lot simpler.

Comment: @gaetanoM I really liked gaetanoM answer. getting first item from jquery selector object works!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you wrote is true (it's enough to debug jQuery source code): the trigger click event doesn't work on an anchor.

In order to achieve what you are trying you can get the dom element and then fire the click:

```
$('a[href="#hash"]').get(0).click()
```

This only will work.

Answer (score 5):

New guy here hopefully not making an azz of himself. I just thought maybe something in this code I'm using on my site might help you. It kinda seems similar to what you're describing.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('a[href^="#"]').on('click',function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    var target = this.hash;
    var $target = $(target);

    $('html, body').stop().animate({
      'scrollTop': $target.offset().top
    }, 900, 'swing', function () {
      window.location.hash = target;
    });
  });
   });
```

Comment: So you are manually changing the location hash, right? I'm wondering why click trigger method is not doing the same thing? Once you call `trigger('click`)` on an element, everything is as user clicks on it but url changes on manual click and not with trigger!

Comment: I didn't know about anchor.hash +1

Comment: Like I said. It just seemed similar to what I read and I hoped something there would trigger a solution! Sorry. Wish I could help more.

I don't know what you mean by manually. The JS works simply after just marking the #locations in HTML.

It's here on [codepen](http://codepen.io/awaybackhome/full/WomzKM/)

Comment: @awaybackhome Your answer might not help me, but believe me, it might  help another developer. +1 for motivating a new user. :)

Answer (score 3):

The `click` method (when used by `jquery`) triggers the `click` events that you register using the `el.click(function..` and `el.on('click', function...`

You can create a new `MouseEvent` and dispatch it directly to the relevant element:

```
e = document.createEvent('MouseEvents');
e.initEvent("click", true, true);
$('a[href="#hash"]')[0].dispatchEvent(e)
```

> The above code will work in Chrome, Firefox and IE

Or just use the `click` event of the element (which will not use jquery's `click` function, but the browser's `click` function):

```
$('a[href="#hash"]')[0].click()
```

> Note that this code might not work in several browsers due to security reasons.

Comment: Isn't jQuery's own trigger click doing this?

Comment: Sorry, but I don't understand. If I trigger click on a link with an actual (url) href, locations gets changed to the given href. But it's not working with a hash-only href. why is that? You are suggesting creating new event for click but I want to know why click is not doing the same thing!

Comment: Are you sure it works? I just checked it on chrome/firefox/ie - the `$('a').click()` on regular link doesn't work... it does nothing.

Comment: It seems that I was wrong. trigger doesn't work on anchor tags as @gaetanoM pointed.

Comment: I faced something else which is confusing me! Is there any difference between `$('a[href="#hash"]')[0].click();` and ```$('a[href="#hash"]')[0].trigger('click');`? First is working and second not! jQuery docs says click  without params is the same as triggre(click).

Comment: As for your first comment - it's also in my answer (you should have read the update correctly). As for the second comment - the second line of your use using `trigger` on the element (and not on the jquery object), and you can't do this. Open the console and check the errors.