# Trying to execute a event with javascript on an <a> element

Tags: javascript, html

The reason i need to execute the event behind a a element is because i'm working on some kind of autologin, however one of the sites it has to work with is https://create.kahoot.it/#login?a=1&next= the problem is, their login uses an a element for the sign in button, however when i select that element and execute a .click on it it simply doesn't do the same thing as to what happens when a user clicks on it.
I hope someone could answer this question since i couldn't find anything close to this issue anywhere.

Also for the convenience of whoever helps, to select the element from the console you could use:
document.getElementById('sign-in').getElementsByTagName('a')[1];

The way to solve this issue has to be either javascript or JQuery, preferably just plain javascript.

Comment: Show us a minimal working example of code.

Comment: I just answered today the exact same question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41447327/triggering-click-on-a-link-doesnt-change-location-hash/41447448#41447448

Comment: If there was i wouldn't be asking, the working part would be manually pressing sign in on kahoot.

Comment: Call the method for that event, for example `element.click()` will trigger the click event for `element`.

Comment: @ Spencer Wieczorek so how about an a element? which in my case doesn't even have an url

Comment: @knowndead It doesn't matter if it's an `a` element.

Comment: it doesn't do anything @Spencer Wieczorek

e = document.createEvent('MouseEvents');
e.initEvent("click", true, true);
$('a[class="btn register"]').get(1).dispatchEvent(e)
also doesn't work which was Dekel his idea(refering to his linked post)
It does work on the register link, just not on the sign in link

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
document.getElementsByClassName('btn register')[0].click();
```

This basically is selecting the anchor by its class name and fire click event manually.

UPDATE:

Alright I did some more research and it seems there is another way of triggering that click handler and it is to set `href` on the `window`:

```
var a = document.getElementsByClassName('btn register')[1];

window.location.href = a.href;
```

I've tried it and seems it is doing the job.

Comment: I see i made a mistake in my original post it is element 1 so that would be
document.getElementsByClassName('btn register')[1].click();


which doesnt work(it is the sign in button)

Comment: I've tested my code and it works, what do you mean by [1]? @knowndead

Comment: Well it is true that document.getElementsByClassName('btn register')[0].click(); works, but that is actually the register buttton on the top right, i need it to work for the sign in button which is a slightly different scenario where your code won't work. Also with element 1 i ment the button with the text sign in